# How to use ng-template inside innerHTML in Angular

Tags: angular, angular2-template, innerhtml, ng-template, angular-dynamic-components

Can someone help me, how to use ng-template inside innerHTML tag,

Stackblitz Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xgnnj4

What I wanted to do is,

In the Component HTML

```
<div [innerHTML]="htmlString"><div>
```

In the Component TS

```
@ViewChild('dynamicComponent', { static: false, read: ViewContainerRef }) myRef: ViewContainerRef;

htmlString = `<ng-template #dynamicComponent></ng-template>`;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(CommentComponent);
    const ref = this.myRef.createComponent(factory);
    ref.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }
```

I really need to achieve this way because I wanted to get the HTML content from an API and use that value to display the HTML content dynamically

As I am getting the error as **Cannot read property 'createComponent' of undefined** but if I put  outside the innerHTML it works perfectly

I have gone through https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader but it's not helping my scneario

Comment: Do you have a pen we can look at ? What exactly is being displayed or are you getting a template error ?

Comment: @SamuelMiddendorp, I don't have pen but I have updated the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are basically trying to do is dynamically load a component inside a dynamically loaded string. Any template either provided inline or separately in an HTML file is processed by the Angular rendering engine. (**Ivy** is the new and optimized rendering engine starting from Angular 9, from Angular 4 till 8 default rendering engine is called `Renderer2` which is the successor to `Renderer` which was the default from Angular 2 till 4).

This is basically what you are trying to do in attached stackBlitz,

```
@ViewChild("dynamicComponent", { static: false, read: ViewContainerRef }) myRef: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
    //Simulate the network call
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.htmlChildString = `<ng-template #dynamicComponent></ng-template>`;
    }, 2000);
  }
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(
      ChildViewComponent
    );
    const ref = this.myRef.createComponent(factory);
    ref.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }
```

first thing which is wrong here is that obviously `ngAfterViewInit`will be called before your `setTimeout` method written in the `constructor` due to your defined timeout of `2000ms`, so `myRef` will always be undefined because its not yet instantiated, next issue which I see is regarding your template,

```
<div [innerHTML]="htmlChildString"></div>
```

`innerHTML` is not supposed to contain any angular symbols, it can only contain plain HTML which can be directly embedded in the DOM since they won't be processed by the Angular rendering engine, which is exactly what @Andriy has already pointed out.

Now coming to the reason why what you are attempting is not possible, Suppose you define a component named `AComponent` having template:

```
<span>I am {{name}}</span>
```

angular compiler, when going through each of your (statically defined) components and templates attached to these component, it creates factory for each component. When angular compiler goes through above template it generates a factory like following,

```
function View_AComponent_0(l) {
    return jit_viewDef1(0,
        [
          jit_elementDef2(0,null,null,1,'span',...),
          jit_textDef3(null,['I am ',...])
        ], 
        null,
        function(_ck,_v) {
            var _co = _v.component;
            var currVal_0 = _co.name;
            _ck(_v,1,0,currVal_0);
```

notice following line?

```
jit_elementDef2(0,null,null,1,'span',...),
```

What Angular is doing is using JS to create elements, Angular uses this factory to instantiate View Definition which in turn is used to create component View. Under the hood Angular represents an application as a tree of views. There is only one instance of a view definition per component type which acts as a template for all views. But for each component instance Angular creates a separate view.

Above factory describes the structure of a component view and is used when instantiating the component. The `jit_viewDef1` is the reference to the `viewDef` function that creates a view definition.
View definition receives view definition nodes as parameters which resemble the structure of the html but also contain many angular specific details.

this factory is what is returned from `resolveComponentFactory` method, since you have statically declared `ChildViewComponent` in your module and also marked it as an `entryComponent`, that's the reason angular decided to pre generate its factory even though it knows its not currently being used by Router or in another component's template.

Similarly `ViewContainerRef` is a reference to a view container (`ng-template` or `ng-container`) which has to be either statically defined directly in the template or which should be be encounter able via a combination of `ngSwitch` or `ngIf` directives, but in any case compiler / rendering engine has to be aware of the presence of this container before hand while compiling.

In your case when you load over these angular symbols dynamically via API, angular only knows this is a simple string and doesn't know before hand that this is some thing which can contain a view at run time. If you ever had a look at the build generated by Angular, it only contain JS files and no HTML template or CSS styling files corresponding to your components. Every template contained with in those HTML files gets transformed into factory methods which are eventually used at run time.

What I would recommend you is to,

1. Either load only pure HTML content over the rest API and pull all angular specific symbols into your angular application and conditionally load them,
   e.g. have a look at this [stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mffs3t?embed=1&file=src/app/cdk-portal-overview-example.ts) there is nothing out of the box happening in it, it just uses CDK Portal which is basically just an abstraction over the methods `resolveComponentFactory` and `createComponent` and a statically defined `templateRef` which is dynamically loaded in the `viewContainerRef` on the click of a button.

[image]

2. Or create another JS or Angular application and pull `ChildViewComponent` in there and have an Iframe load up the content based on any condition if required,
3. Load up a compiled version of your template similar to how angular lazy loads its modules, and some how load that in an router outlet programmatically. I don't know if this is even possible or not this is just an idea in my mind but I don't expect this to be straight forward.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) to pass any HTML to template:

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

...

export class HelloComponent  {
  htmlString = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(`
    <ng-template>
      <div style="width: 10px; height: 10px; background: red;"></div>
    </ng-template>
  `);

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
}
```

STACKBLITZ: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t9roxg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

keep in mind that in this way HTML is passed as plain HTML without any Angular processing

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, I had forgot to mention I was using child component inside ng-template and I have updated the question, Can you help with that, What is wrong

Comment: Try to follow Angular original demo at https://stackblitz.com/angular/kbayapnxprb. I will look at it later tonight

Comment: Thanks @Andriy I have tried it already the problem was in the above tutorial there are not loading child the way I am loading

Comment: So, please try to share your stackblitz example, so I can observe it and try to help

Comment: Okay sure, I will create it now

Comment: I am sorry that I forgot to create the stackblitz But now I have created one and I am seeing the error in the console can you pleas take a look
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xgnnj4